# Code block preview - inconsistent rendering of backslashes

Tags: bug, editor, markdown-preview

Here's a screenshot of a post edit on Stack Overflow:

[image]

Note the double backslashes (part of Java syntax) and how they render in preview. When the post is actually committed, the double backslashes are reduced to single backslashes.

[image]

Known problem?

Comment: Your "paper rips" and lack of use of freehand circles is bothering me.

Comment: Yes, the lack of FHS has my mouse hovering over that downvote button.